# Increasing width of Views 3 search form filter

Tags: 7, views

I am trying to increase the size of my views search filter form. The form id is views-exposed-form-blog--user-s-tab--page and am trying to use this in code I've used for my search block but its not working.

Here's my search block code -

```
function Themename_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'search_block_form') {
    $form['search_block_form']['#size'] = 26; 
  }
}
```

Any ideas how I can make this work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you can get away with a simple CSS rule in your theme's stylesheet? Something like this:

```
#views-exposed-form-blog--user-s-tab--page input{width: 200px;}
```

That width can be anything. In this example, it'd be 200pixels wide.